# .once() never fires whenComplete() in flutter using realtimedatabase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

In flutter web,

"In then" is never called. I have tried this with adding an async and await to the kDatabase call, and calling it without async. The `whenComplete` block is never called either.

What could possibly be happening? No errors are ever caught. Any help or perspective would be greatly appreciated.

```
 void getpostDetail(String? postID) {
    print("Before try");
    try {
        print("In try 1");
        assert(postID != null);
        print("In try 2");
        kDatabase
            .child('post')
            .child(postID!)
            .once()
            .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
          print("In then");
        }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
          print("in catchError");
        }).whenComplete(() => print("In whenComplete"));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("In error");
    } finally {
      print("In finally");
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:
I enabled logs via:

```
FirebaseDatabase fd = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
fd.setLoggingEnabled(true);
DatabaseReference dr = fd.ref();
dr.child('post').child
.child(postID!)
.once()
.then
```

And I see

```
03:36:33.833Z","description":"lets
repl","lanCode":"auto","parentkey":"-MxvCNmiJ9lRNX8XkwL4","retweetCount":0,"user":{"displayName":"Hunte
r","isVerified":false,"profilePic":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzDG366qY7vXN
2yng09wb517WTWqp-oua-mMsAoCadtncPybfQ&s","userId":"va9C2IQ4ITf1zzfhKQvd7cZdncl2","userName":"@Hunterva9
c"},"userId":"va9C2IQ4ITf1zzfhKQvd7cZdncl2"}
```

And `"In finally"` gets called. But `"In then"`,`"in catchError"`,`"In whenComplete"` are never called and I don't have my data available where I need it.

Comment: Could it be that the device/browser is unable to reach the database server?

Comment: if that was the case, wouldn't it error?

Comment: Also, I'm using this same database in many other places in my app and it does work, but its a large codebase that I just started diving into, and many things could be happening that I am not fully aware of

Comment: 1. No, I don't think so. 2. It might be useful in that case to [enable debug logging](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/setLoggingEnabled.html) and check what it outputs when this `once()` statement executes.

Comment: Updated question with info on logging, would appreciate if you can take a look, thank you.

Comment: That log seems to indicate that the data is being read. I tried to reproduce the problem (unsuccessfully), and (since it's rather long) posted it as an answer below.

Comment: Ok. I was able to run the above code in a standalone project. So I'm 99% sure there is something else affecting this. Voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the problem on Chrome, but am unable to. My code:

```
print("Before try");
try {
  print("In try 1");
  print("In try 2");
  database.ref('71163140/chats')
      .child('oF1b6J4Hz3NGzRb9RmSVFGJdcYi1')
      .once()
      .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
    print("In then");
  }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
    print("in catchError");
  }).whenComplete(() => print("In whenComplete"));
} catch (error) {
  print("In catch");
} finally {
  print("In finally");
}
```

The ouput:

> Before try
>
> In try 1
>
> In try 2
>
> In finally
>
> In then
>
> In whenComplete

Even when I try to read a non-existing node that is the flow, which makes sense as reading a non-existing node is not an error.

The only way I can get it to fail is by adding `FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOffline()` before the code, in which case the output becomes:

> Error: [firebase_database/unknown] Error: Client is offline.

So I'm not sure what is going on in your case. You might want to see if changing the library version makes any difference, but I don't think there were any changes in this area recently.

Comment: K. Fixing my shower valves today. I likely get to analyzing the issue tomorrow. Thank you very much for assisting.